# load large data in REST API - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am using `PostgreSQL` database with `Ruby` and `Rails 3.2.13`. We already created `200K` rows of records in `PostgreSQL` database. I need to send the same 200K records to another standalone `windows application`.I created a ROR REST API for this purpose. Currently the REST API takes long time to process the data and gets time out after 3 mins.

I am sending 1000 records at a time so that the API will send 1 - 1000 then 1001 - 2000 and so on. This is avoiding the time out. Is this a good approach in handling bulk data.

Do ROR have any build in function to handle this type of operation. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get the solution? Can anybody help with it?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no I don't think this is a good approach for transferring bulk data.

Putting the security concerns aside (which is reason itself not to), you'll need to handle data/schema consistency, connection reliability, datatype integrity, parsing and sanitizing strings, serialization/deserialization, etc... Sounds like a huge headache to me.

Bulk data transfer between databases isn't a responsibility/concern of Rails. I'd stick to doing this entirely on the backend and set up a new database as a replication slave of the master.

Comment: Replication is not doable in my case, because the standalone application is a .net app and is installed in individual machine. Can it be good by handling with the help of web services. Please advise.